# struct/class bit field packing

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I'd like to use the bit field feature of cpp.
However i get all kind of strange behivours and i was wondering if there is 
a way to constrain the compiler.

I'd like to use this bit field:

```
class MyBitField
{
   uint32 a :  8;
   uint32 b : 32;
   uint32 c : 32;
}
```

Now using this code:

```
uint8 rawData[9] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x9A, 0xBC, 0xDE, 0xFF, 0xFF};
MyBitField \*pMyBitField = (MyBitField\*)rawData;
```

I expect(on little endian 32bit CPU): 
the a's field of the pMyBitField  to be 0x12,
the b's field of the pMyBitField  to be 0x9A785634,
the a's field of the pMyBitField  to be 0xFFFFDEBC.

The compiler choose to make some unexplained alignment.
I know that in case you use different types inside the bit filed you might get alignment, but this is not the case.
How can i do it?

Let's focused on Visual Studio 2005 but any other env support will be blessed as well.

*I read some post of packing but it did not change the alignment problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Google #pragma pack, which is an instruction to the compiler to use particular alignment within structures....

Comment: Hi Tony, please elaborate the $pragma usage

Comment: first match from Google, relates specifically to your compiler, includes examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Standard 9.6-1 (albeit old draft) "Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit. [Note: bit-fields straddle allocation units on some machines and not on others.".  So, whether it works depends on your compiler... you say "I read some post of packing but it did not change the alignment problem." - what did you try, what result did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd expect your code not to compile.  `rawData` has an array type; this
implicitly converts to a pointer, but cannot be converted to a class
type, implicitly or explicitly.

For the rest, how the compiler lays out bit fields is implementation
defined, but in your case, I'd expect it to be irrelevant; on a 32 bit
machine, a 32 bit bitfield will normally force the compiler to use the
next word, so only the first bit field has any effect.  Depending on the
compiler, it will cause the compiler to put the value on either the high
order 8 bits, or the low order 8 bits (and leave the rest of the word
undefined).

If you need to match an external format, the only way of doing this
reliably is byte by byte, inserting whatever value is necessary for that
byte.

Comment: Visual Studio does suggest Intel/AMD, where CPUs are capable of unaligned addressing (sometimes with a performance penalty).  I would expect the compiler to honour a pack request for non-performance-optimal alignment.  "only way of doing this reliably..." may be true if you equate reliable with portable and guaranteed consistent across compiler versions etc., but if you're prepared to use implementation defined behaviour it may well be defined and implemented reliably....

Comment: If packing were the only issue, and you're not concerned about portability, you might be able to use pragmas.  In practice, anytime packing is an issue, so it byte order, and possibly other things.